# React Testing, with Jest screen not refreshing

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

I am having trouble at the end of the test.  The test is to login in a user and the screen on successful login should refresh and a list appears on the screen.  The login is successful, but the list is not showing.  Do I need to do a rerender or something?  The screen.debug() at the bottom is what I am using to verify that the list is not showing.  I can see the login screen appear.

```
describe("<App />", () => {
    let server: any = null;
    beforeEach(() => {
        server = makeServer({ environment : "test" });
      });
     
      afterEach(() => {
        server.shutdown()
      });
      test("Login", async () => {
        render(<App />);

        const btnLogin = screen.getByText(/Login/i) as HTMLButtonElement;
        expect(btnLogin.disabled).toBe(false);
        const user = userEvent.setup();
        await user.click(btnLogin);
        
        let btnOk = screen.getByText(/OK/i) as HTMLButtonElement;
        expect(btnOk.disabled).toBe(true);

        let btnCancel = screen.getByText(/Cancel/i) as HTMLButtonElement;
        expect(btnCancel.disabled).toBe(false);

        const txt = screen.getByLabelText(/Access Code/i) as HTMLInputElement;
        fireEvent.change(txt, { target: { value: 'USER' } });

        await user.click(btnOk);
        screen.debug();
      });

});
```

Comment: have you tried awaiting for that list with the `waitFor` method?  https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor

Comment: Your comment worked please move to an answer and I will approve it.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make changes in the DOM via rerendering you should always use `waitFor`:

```
await waitFor(() => {
  expect(btnOk).toBeInTheDocument();
});
// then you can assert the rest of the elements without the need of waitFor
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```js
await user.type(txt, 'USER');
```

instead of using `fireEvent`?

you should also make sure that the `btnOk` is not disabled anymore before clicking it.